# Flutter offset the appbar title to the left

Tags: flutter

I am creating page for my application and I have created the appbar with a leading icon. However, the space between the icon and the title is very large and to me, looks off.

I do I offset/push the title of the appbar to the left a little.

**code:**

```
appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
            iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        );
        },
    ),
    title: Text("Student Finance",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
),
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// Add everything under title widgets and make leading false

```
AppBar(
    title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[  
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left, size: 32.0),
            ),
            Text("Student Finance"),
        ],
    ),
    titleSpacing: 0.0,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
),
```

Comment: When I tried that it moved the back icon to the right rather than the title to the left. Results in large space between left side of the screen and icon.

Comment: If I added `titleSpacing: 0.0,` at the bottom it sorted the previousily mentioned spacing issue. Works perfectly now